# Undocumented breaking change in jQuery 1.5.2

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin, [CheckTree](http://static.geewax.org/checktree/index.html) to implement a tree of selectable items. The demo page (link above) brings in jQuery 1.2.6 ... as you might expect, my site has something much newer.

Trial and error has established that the demo stops working with jQuery versions 1.5.2 or later.  Interestingly, the [release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/03/31/jquery-152-released/comment-page-1/) say that jQuery 1.5.2 is just a bugfix release, and introduces no breaking changes.  I've boiled the problem down to its simplest form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Breaking change in jQuery 1.5.2?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <button>Click me</button>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $(':checkbox').change(function(){ console.log('input checkbox change event'); });
                $("button").click(function(){
                    console.log('button clicked');
                    $(":checkbox").click();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In jQuery 1.5.1, the change event of the checkbox is not triggered when the button is clicked.  In jQuery 1.5.2, the change event *is* triggered.

Put another way, when using jQuery 1.5.1, clicking the button results in the following console output:

```
button clicked
```

When using jQuery 1.5.2, the following is logged when the button is clicked:

```
button clicked
input checkbox change event
```

Is there any documentation to explain why this change has taken place, and what I can do to work around it?  The plugin requires that the checkbox change event is not triggered by `$(":checkbox").click()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this was more of a bug being fixed rather than breaking functionality. In other words, the CheckTree plugin was relying on a jQuery bug, and thus the plugin broke when the bug was fixed.

I've just confirmed this with one of the the jQuery devs. He says:

> I remember that one well. Some DOM methods should end up firing multiple events if you invoke them. It was a bug that older jQuery did not allow this. As far as it being a 'breaking change', well... it was 'fixing change' for a lot of people. If you depended on the bug then yeah, your code broke.

Here's the relevant pull request from github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/260

Hope that answers the question.

Comment: Thanks. I read the release notes several times, and even though fix 7340 was listed, I just didn't see it as having an impact on me. Then there's the issue of semantics too ... IMHO a "fixing change" can be a breaking change which makes things better, presumably according to the majority. I count myself in that majority by the way.

Comment: Definition of breaking change from wiktionary: "A change in one part of a software system that causes other parts to fail; occurs most often in shared libraries of code used by multiple applications".  According to that definition, I'd say it was a breaking change. At least I understand the why and the how now, so thanks for that. It also means I'm happy with my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a work around, but I still want to see the documentation for the altered behaviour to understand what's going on!

The workaround relies on the fact that the above JavaScript can be rewritten as:

```
$(function(){
    $(':checkbox').bind('change',function(){ console.log('input checkbox change event'); });
    $("button").click(function(){
        console.log('button clicked');
        $(":checkbox").click();
    });
});
```

I.e. I've replaced `change(fn)` with `bind('change',fn)`.  There are two places in the plugin which explicitly call `change()` on checkboxes, so they can be similarly rewritten as `trigger('change')`.

The final piece of the jigsaw was to rename the `change` event to something else, like `foo` (as it's no longer a keyword and is just a string).

Now that the event binding is to `foo`, rather than `change`, the call to `click()` does not cause it to fire in any version of jQuery, and we explcitly call it using `trigger('foo')` when we need it to fire.